# () in Function Variable and Application

Tags: haskell

The [Types and Functions lecture](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/11/24/types-and-functions/) presents the function:

```
f44 :: () -> Integer
f44 () = 44
```

I typed the following:

```
ghci> let f () = 5
ghci> f ()
5
```

But, I'm confused by the `()` in `let f ()`. Typically, as a beginner, I've seen  an immutable variable following the function name, i.e. `f`.

What is the name of `()` when it's listed after `let f ...`? How about when it's used in the function application, `f ()`?

Comment: You could just as easily write `let f :: () -> Integer; f x = 5`, but the difference would be that `f undefined` wouldn't throw an error.  Defining it with pattern matching as `f () = 5` means that the argument has to be fully evaluated to `()` before the function returns 5.

Comment: Please read this blog post carefully. The examples only illustrate comparisons of the usefulness of types. They shouldn't considered sane Haskell coding style.

Comment: cf. CAF memoization (google it). sometimes you tack a () onto your list-producing computation in hopes of *an interpreter* not memoizing it as a result (so you can test its performance better). (`primes = ...` vs. `primes () = ...` vs. `primesTo n = ...` ; of which the last is (more or less) guaranteed to be actually recalculated for each new call to `primesTo 10`; as an example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"()" is usually pronounced "unit".

In Haskell, it is both the name of a type, as seen in

```
f44 :: () -> Integer
```

and the name of the only value that exists of that type, as seen in

```
f44 () = 44
```

where it is used for pattern matching.

This more familiar-looking definition would provide an equivalent but more verbose type:

```
data Unit = Unit
f45 :: Unit -> Integer
f45 Unit = 45
```

Nothing stops you from binding `()` to a name, just like you can for any other value:

```
Prelude> let f () = 5
Prelude> :t f
f :: Num a => () -> a
Prelude> let name = ()
Prelude> :t name
name :: ()
Prelude> name
()
Prelude> f name
5
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about this function:

```
f44 :: () -> Integer
f44 () = 44
```

The key thing to understand here is that `()` is the type with only a  single inhabitant value `()`. So the type `()` can have only a value of `()`. In fact it's [defined](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/ghc-prim/src/GHC-Tuple.html#%28%29) like this:

```
data () = ()
```

When you do this in ghci:

```
λ> let f () = 5
```

You are creating a function of type `Num a => () -> a`. You can
inspect that yourself in ghci:

```
λ> :t f
f :: Num a => () -> a
```

> What is the name of () when it's listed after let f ...?

You are using pattern matching to implement a function `f` which given a value of `()` gives you `5`.

> How about when it's used in the function application, f ()?

It's the usual function application. You are applying a value of `()` to the function `f` and that will produce `5` according to your function definition.

Answer (score 1):

`()` is called Unit or empty tuple. It holds no value.

In function definition, parentheses on the left side of the `=` are usually only used to pattern match your function parameters.

In your example, the `()` is practically useless. Your function would work without it and would be a zero parameter function then.

```
f44 :: Integer
f44 = 44
```