# Who invented proxy passing and when?

Tags: haskell, types

It seems that until recent years, the usual way to pass an extra type to a function was to do something like

```
f (undefined :: T)
```

Kiselyov and Shan even used this approach in their classic paper on class-based reflection that inspired the `reflection` package. They excused the obvious ugliness by noting that the bogus value is never inspected. And an only slightly less ugly incarnation appears in `Data.Bits.finiteBitSize`, which takes a value it ignores to get its type.

Then *someone* figured out the proxy idiom, and everything changed. Now we always see the much more satisfactory

```
f (Proxy :: Proxy T)
```

(in standard code—GHC type application is another story).

Who figured it out? Did this first appear in code somewhere, or a paper?

Comment: I first saw Proxy in Edward's [tagged](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.1.0/docs/Data-Tagged.html) package, fwiw.  It wasn't in 0.0 but was in 0.1.

Comment: Interesting question. On other news, I just saw the _history_ tag remark "DO NOT use this tag for questions about the history of a programming concept or feature; those questions are off-topic.". Sometimes SO policies are surprising. (And yes, this comment is also a bit OT here).

Answer (score 21):

A *fantastic* question. [TypeLevelReasoning](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeLevelReasoning), an early GHC proposal from April 2013, references the `libraries` thread ["Proxy, new Typeable, and type-level equality"](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-April/019653.html) (original poster Richard Eisenberg, the driving force behind many of the recent dependent Haskell work). That thread references another `libraries` thread ["Proxy and new-typeable"](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-January/019343.html) (original poster Shachaf Ben-Kiki), which was started in response to a patch from the `new-typeable` branch. It is difficult to find a record of old branch names and which commits they pointed at, but [commit 3d53407 by José Pedro Magalhães](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/3d53407f9c6e87bcff30d51f0a048e92b2745a32) seems to be the squashed version of that branch. Indeed it appears to be the first commit landing in GHC to introduce a `data Proxy t = Proxy` type. Eisenberg would later move that type to `Data.Proxy` in [commit 01aa22b](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commits/master/libraries/base/Data/Proxy.hs) in February 2013. The final design of `Proxy` seems to be collective synthesis of ideas from many people. However, we can find academic references to `Proxy` in Magalhães' work, such as his presentation ["The right Kind of Generic Programming"](https://web.archive.org/save/_embed/http://foswiki.cs.uu.nl/foswiki/pub/GP/Schedule/LieweVanBinsbergen.pdf) (October 2012) and his blog post ["Coming soon in GHC HEAD: poly-kinded Typeable"](https://web.archive.org/save/http://hauptwerk.blogspot.com/2012/11/coming-soon-in-ghc-head-poly-kinded.html) (November 2012). We can probably attribute the inclusion of `Proxy` in base to him.

However, the idea of a `Proxy` type seems much older:

- ["Giving Haskell a promotion"](https://web.archive.org/save/http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/dimitris/fc-kind-poly.pdf) by Yorgey, Cretin, SPJ (October 2011)
- ["Scrap your boilerplate with class"](https://web.archive.org/save/http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/gmap3.pdf) by Lammel, Jones (ICFP 2005)

It is here that my Google searches turn up dry. I cannot seem to find an antecedent to that 2005 paper.

Coda: Shachaf's proposal in that thread, of universally quantifying the proxy type by using `forall proxy a. proxy a` (which the base libraries still use to this day) instead of `forall a. Proxy a` is itself interesting, as that and other emails in the thread suggest there at one point might have been multiple instances of `Proxy` floating around the Haskell ecosystem. As mentioned in the comments, [Kmett's tagged library had it back in June 2010](https://github.com/ekmett/tagged/commit/4f08e84c78ea3a77f6c270ddf169588e99b67dc2).

Comment: *Fantastic* research!

Comment: Universally quantifying proxy is useful when users of a library are probably already in possession of an `f a` for some `f`. For example `datatypeName :: Datatype d => t d (f :: * -> *) a -> [Char]` [from Generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Datatype) is a funny-kinded `Datatype d => proxy d -> [Char]` that's convenient for someone who is holding an `M1 D d f p` meta node of a generic representation.

Comment: Interestingly, Lammel and Jones describe their technique as standard. Also interestingly, it is definitely *not* the modern proxy technique. Their `Proxy a` is uninhabited, for vague reasons that don't really seem sensible.

Comment: [pigworker's explanation of `()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112439/what-does-mean-in-haskell/33115522#33115522) gets at the heart of why Lammel and Jones were wrong about that, and why the modern `Proxy` is right.

Comment: @Cirdec, it's also sometimes convenient to be able to pass a singleton as a proxy.