# Avoiding Overlapping Instances with Closed Type Families (GHC/AdvancedOverlap)

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Any pointers on how to make the closed type family example from the Haskell Wiki compile?

[GHC/AdvancedOverlap](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) (Solution 3)

Here is the version I tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    DataKinds,
    FlexibleInstances,
    MultiParamTypeClasses,
    TypeFamilies,
    UndecidableInstances #-}

data HTrue
data HFalse

type family ShowPred a where
  ShowPred Int   = HTrue
  ShowPred Bool  = HTrue
  ShowPred [a]   = ShowPred a
  ShowPred a     = HFalse

class Print a where
  print :: a -> IO ()

instance (ShowPred a ~ flag, Print' flag a) => Print a where
  print = print' (undefined :: flag)

class Print' flag a where
  print' :: flag -> a -> IO ()

instance Show a => Print' HTrue a where
  print' _ x = putStrLn (show x)

instance Print' flag a where
  print' _ _ = putStrLn "No show method"
```

However, this still gives me:

> Overlapping instances for Print' flag0 a.

(GHC 8.0.1 is the version I am using.)

**Edit:** Defining the second instance as `Print' HFalse a` results in:

> Could not deduce (Print' flag0 a) arising from a use of print' from the context: (ShowPred a ~ flag, Print' flag a).

**Edit:** Here is the example with all the corrections. All credit goes to @dfeuer.

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    DataKinds,
    FlexibleInstances,
    MultiParamTypeClasses,
    ScopedTypeVariables,
    TypeFamilies,
    UndecidableInstances #-}

import Prelude hiding (print)

import Data.Proxy

data HTrue
data HFalse

type family ShowPred a where
  ShowPred Int   = HTrue
  ShowPred Bool  = HTrue
  ShowPred [a]   = ShowPred a
  ShowPred a     = HFalse

class Print a where
  print :: a -> IO ()

instance (ShowPred a ~ flag, Print' flag a) => Print a where
  print = print' (Proxy :: Proxy flag)

class Print' flag a where
  print' :: Proxy flag -> a -> IO ()

instance Show a => Print' HTrue a where
  print' _ x = putStrLn (show x)

instance Print' HFalse a where
  print' _ _ = putStrLn "No show method"
```

Comment: Try `instance Print' HFalse a` for your second instance

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it sounds reasonable, but unfortunately results in another error (see edit).

Comment: @dfeuer Awesome, that works! If you post a very short explanation in an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial error was caused by

```
instance Show a => Print' HTrue a where
  print' _ x = putStrLn (show x)

instance Print' flag a where
  print' _ _ = putStrLn "No show method"
```

These instances overlap when `flag ~ HTrue`. The solution to this is to replace the second instance with

```
instance Print' HFalse a where ...
```

Your next problem was with

```
instance (ShowPred a ~ flag, Print' flag a) => Print a where
  print = print' (undefined :: flag)
```

By default, the `flag` variable in the instance context is not in scope in the instance body, so `undefined :: flag` has an ambiguous type. The solution is to enable `ScopedTypeVariables`.

My final note is that instead of making `print'` take a value of type `flag` and then passing it `undefined`, you should probably use

```
print' :: proxy flag -> a -> IO ()
```

and then import `Data.Proxy` to define

```
print = print' (Proxy :: Proxy flag)
```

The modern proxy-passing approach seems to be quite new, although less-satisfactory versions have been around for some time. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261593/who-invented-proxy-passing-and-when) for some historical context.

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks! I have incorporated the suggestions into a complete working example.

Comment: Interesting! I don't mind the proxy though, seems a lot cleaner than `undefined`. Thanks again!

Comment: @kloffy, uh... actually, that alternate approach doesn't work here. Sorry! Forget that!