# Inverse of the absurd function

Tags: haskell, category-theory

Is there an inverse to the `absurd` function from `Data.Void`?

If it exists, how is it implemented and what is it used for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This function does not exist.** (assuming strict semantics)

Looking at the algebra of types, the function type is equivalent to exponentiation.

Now the function `absurd`, which has the type `Void -> a` corresponds to the operation `a ^ 0` which equals `1`. This means that there is exactly one implementation of `absurd`, which can be found in `Data.Void`.

Reversing the arrow, you get the type `a -> Void`, which corresponds to `0 ^ a` or `0`, which means the desired function does not exist.

---

You could also prove this using the Curry-Howard isomorphism. Since the function type corresponds to the boolean function 'implies', you get the following term:

```
True -> False
```

which is false, and therefore no function `a -> Void` can exist.

*Corrections due to imprecise language are encouraged since I just started learning category theory.*

Comment: Here's a good post [on the 'algebra' in 'algebraic data type'](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/)

Comment: The link in Zoey Hewll's comment is dead but found a mirror: https://gist.github.com/gregberns/5e9da0c95a9a8d2b6338afe69310b945

Answer (score 7):

It depends what you mean. `absurd` witnesses one side of the isomorphism `Void = forall a.a` and from that view, has an inverse

```
void :: (forall a.a) -> Void
void x = x
```

that is really an isomorphism.

There is no total function of the type

```
 forall a.a -> Void
```

nor any inverse to `absurd` with that type among partial functions.

Answer (score 7):

Quite intuitively, that function cannot possibly exist<sup>†</sup>. Say we had such a function:

```
drusba :: a -> Void
```

then you could do

```
GHCi> drusba (5 :: Int)
```

...thereby creating a value of type `Void`. [Well, that's exciting... also, congratulations, you're dead!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33115522/745903)

**Hask** (the category of Haskell types, with Haskell functions as morphisms) is a [bicartesian closed category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category) with [initial object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) `Void`. The definition of an initial object is that, for any type `A`, there exists exactly one function `Void -> A` – these functions are the instantiations of `absurd :: Void -> a`. Dually, there exists exactly one function `B -> ()`, since `()` is the terminal object – any such function is equivalent to `const ()`.

Now, assuming `drusba :: () -> Void`, we would have

```
drusba . absurd :: Void -> Void
drusba . absurd ≡ id
```

because there can only be one function `Void -> Void`, and we know `id` is one; and

```
absurd . drusba :: () -> ()
absurd . drusba ≡ id
```

for the same reason. IOW, `drusba` and `absurd` are indeed proper inverses to each other, which means `()` and `Void` are isomorphic.

But from this it would follow that *any* type `A` is actually isomorphic to both `()` and `Void`, because there would exist precisely one function `() -> A` and `A -> ()`.

So basically, if there existed a function `drusba :: a -> Void`, it would mean that Haskell had only one type, which would contain no values. That wouldn't be a particularly useful programming language, would it?

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Of course, all of this only holds if you disregard ⊥.</sub>

Comment: @dfeuer: _exiting_ or _exciting_, when you're dying it's all the same isn't it?

Comment: Heh. I suppose so.