# How is Data.Void.absurd different from ⊥?

Tags: haskell

I saw [Inverse of the absurd function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38553622/625403) earlier today, and while it's clear to me that any possible implementation of `drusba :: a -> Void` will never terminate (after all, it's impossible to construct `Void`), I don't understand why the same isn't true of `absurd :: Void -> a`. Consider the GHC implementation:

```
newtype Void = Void Void

absurd :: Void -> a
absurd a = a `seq` spin a where
   spin (Void b) = spin b
```

`spin`, it seems to me, is endlessly unraveling the infinite series of `Void` newtype wrappers, and would never return even if you could find a `Void` to pass it. An implementation that would be indistinguishable would be something like:

```
absurd :: Void -> a
absurd a = a `seq` undefined
```

Given that, why do we say that `absurd` is a proper function that deserves to live in Data.Void, but

```
drusba :: a -> Void
drusba = undefined
```

is a function that cannot possibly be defined? Is it something like the following?

> `absurd` is a total function, giving a non-bottom result for any input in its (empty) domain, whereas `drusba` is partial, giving bottom results for some (indeed all) inputs in its domain.

Comment: Barring bottom, the absurd function will never be called.  It is rarely needed, but there are uses for it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Data.Void` moved from the `void` package to `base` in base version `4.8` (GHC 7.10). If you look at the Cabal file for `void` you'll see that it only includes `Data.Void` for old `base` versions. [Now, `Void` is defined as chi suggests](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Void.html#Void):

```
data Void

absurd :: Void -> a
absurd a = case a of {}
```

which is perfectly valid.

---

I think the idea behind the old definition is something like this:

Consider the type

```
data BadVoid = BadVoid BadVoid
```

This type doesn't get the job done, because it's actually possible to define a non-bottom (coinductive) value with that type:

```
badVoid = BadVoid badVoid
```

We can fix that problem by using a strictness annotation, which forces the type to be inductive:

```
data Void = Void !Void
```

Under assumptions that may or may not actually hold, but at least morally hold, we can legitimately perform induction on any inductive type. So

```
spin (Void x) = spin x
```

will always terminate if, hypothetically, we have something of type `Void`.

The final step is replacing the single-strict-constructor datatype with a newtype:

```
newtype Void = Void Void
```

This is legitimate too; it's impossible to construct a non-bottom value of this `Void` type. The advantage of doing it this way is that it sometimes lets GHC recognize a little code as dead. But it's not a big advantage, and it introduces some unfortunate complications. The definition of `spin`, has changed meaning because of the different pattern matching semantics between `data` and `newtype`. To preserve the meaning precisely, `spin` should probably have been written

```
spin !x = case x of Void x' -> spin x'
```

(avoiding `spin !(Void x)` to skirt a now-fixed bug in the interaction between newtype constructors and bang patterns; but for GHC 7.10 (ha!) this form doesn't actually produce the desired error message because it's "optimized" into an infinite loop) at which point `absurd = spin`.

Thankfully, it doesn't actually matter in the end, because the whole old definition is a bit of a silly exercise.

Answer (score 23):

For historical reasons, any Haskell data type (including `newtype`) must have at least one constructor.

Hence, to define the `Void` in "Haskell98" one needs to rely on type-level recursion `newtype Void = Void Void`. There is no (non-bottom) value of this type.

The `absurd` function has to rely on (value level) recursion to cope with the "weird" form of the `Void` type.

In more modern Haskell, with some GHC extensions, we can define a zero constructor data type, which would lead to a saner definition.

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls, EmptyCase #-}
data Void
absurd :: Void -> a
absurd x = case x of { }    -- empty case
```

The case is exhaustive -- it does handle all the constructors of `Void`, all zero of them. Hence it is total.

In some other functional languages, like Agda or Coq, a variant of the case above is idiomatic when dealing with empty types like `Void`.

Comment: We actually *do* that now; see my answer.

Comment: `data Void : Set where MkVoid : Void → Void` is a perfectly valid definition in Agda. So is `Inductive Void : Type := MkVoid : Void -> Void.` in Coq. And you can define the corresponding `absurd` functions just fine.

Comment: `EmptyDataDecls` is part of Haskell 2010. `EmptyCase`, sadly, is not.