# What does () mean in a Haskell function signature?

Tags: haskell

I have the following function in my Haskell file:

```
notFound :: () -> IO ()
notFound = putStr "Sorry, your command could not be found"
```

That function doesn't compile. This is the compile error I get:

```
todos.hs:27:12:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘() -> IO ()’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
    Possible cause: ‘putStr’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the expression: putStr "Sorry, your command could not be found"
    In an equation for ‘notFound’:
        notFound = putStr "Sorry, your command could not be found"
```

But the following function does:

```
    notFound :: IO ()
    notFound = putStr "Sorry, your command could not be found"
```

**Question:**

From my understanding of the type signature, it would seem that these are the same, that `()` means that no arguments are passed into the function. Is that not the case? If not, what does `()` in a function signature mean then?

Comment: hmm... this seems to be a pretty good answer to my question. `()` is a specific type different from not passing anything (duh!). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970012/in-function-variable-and-application

Comment: Guess, I'm still not sure when you would do `notFound ()` vs `notFound` to invoke a function

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112439/what-does-mean-in-haskell help

Comment: I guess now I'm curious when I would use `()` in a type signature vs just not using anything?

Comment: that's a deep question. perhaps it would help to look at all the functions that you've used that have () in the type signature. do you notice any commonality between them?

Comment: "the following function [...] `notFound :: IO ()`" - I think perhaps this is the root of your confusion: What you're defining there isn't a function. It's a value of type `IO ()`. The function type is `(->)`. It's a totally different thing.

Comment: Means that you have pass a value of type `()` (Unit type) as paramenter and the only value with that type is `()` as well. Meaning of `()`: there is no information here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`()` is the empty tuple. It's not nothing, it's more like the void type in C-like languages or a fixed length list of length zero. There's exactly one object with the type: `() :: ()`, unlike something like `Bool`.

So why have this? Generally, I've seen it used to "close" one of the variables in a type. So `IO ()` is an `IO` operation which always returns the same thing: `()`.

A possibly better example would be: `Conduit a IO b` is something that takes some stream of type `a` objects and transforms it into a stream of `b` objects. But what if you have something that doesn't accept an input stream? You can represent it as a `Conduit () IO b` to "close off" the input stream. (I'm playing loose and fast with the definitions here, but I think it still more or less works)

Comment: Oh, ok, ok. This makes sense. So it's not so much as having `()` as an argument you pass into a function, but more about having a function with side effects RETURN `()`. Right?

Comment: Yes. A function that has type `f :: () -> a` can easily be resolved to `a` by doing `f () :: a`, but IO is defined as always returning something so you have to put something in the slot. If this still isn't too clear, it could help that `IO a` is defined in the background as a function taking the "state of the real world" and returning the tuple `("[new] state of the real world", a)`.

Comment: Careful with using `Void` – that [usually refers to an *empty* type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7.1/docs/Data-Void.html), i.e. `data Void` with no constructors.  (Although yes, `void` return types in C-like languages correspond to `()` and not the empty `Void`.)

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky Great point. I had intended to show similarity, but you're right that it could be confusing. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your `notFound` function is defining a function that takes a value of type `()`, and returns a value of type `IO()`.  `()` is the only value of type `()`.  Your function is unintentionally in point-free notation

```
notFound :: () -> IO ()
notFound = putStr "Sorry, your command could not be found"
```

is equivalent to

```
notFound :: () -> IO ()
notFound () = putStr "Sorry, your command could not be found" ()
```

This obviously doesn't work because the function `putStrLn` does not accept `()` as a second argument.

You could of course define it as

```
notFound :: () -> IO ()
notFound () = putStr "Sorry, your command could not be found"
```

This would compile, but is fairly nonsensical, since it would need to be invoked as `notFound ()`.

What you actually want is just the IO action, not a function.  So you can just define it as `notFound :: IO()`.